# Weird navigation text behavior on hover

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, css-transitions, background-color

[image]

I'm having a css issue that I'm having trouble debugging. I made a 'highlight' effect on hover in the main navigation, where it appears to highlight a little behind & below the text. This is working as expected.

But on the two longer nav links, exiting the hover state results in the text appearing to slide in from the right, like it was shrunk & expands when the hover state ends.

You can see this in the gif above - the hover states work perfectly, but when leaving the hover state, the text in the 2nd & 4th nav links seems to reset & slide in from the right.

I'm stumped on this - I've never seen anything like this, and this theme (Astra) is new to me. Obviously there's something different with the hover state than the non-hover state. Maybe this has something to do with the nav text being aligned right? I don't know :/

You can see this live at https://allytutoring.com/writing-resources/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your hover effect: in the :before selector, on hover, you set the position to "absolute", which means when the item is *not* hovered over, the content is position is static - so it "pushes" your menu item.

You should try and put everything that will not change in your initial state, and only add css properties that change to your hover selector:

```
#primary-menu .menu-link::before { /* This is your initial state */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(47,139,255,0.8);
    height: .8em;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-duration: .25s;
 }
 #primary-menu .menu-link:hover::before { /* This is your hover state */
    width: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks - that was wise advice. Based on your advice, I adjusted the css to this and it now works as expected:

`#primary-menu .menu-link::before {
 width:0; 
  content: '';
 display: block;
  transition-duration:.25s;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: rgba(47,139,255,0.8);
 height: .8em;
 top: 1.5em;
 left: 5%;
 z-index: 1;
}

#primary-menu .menu-link:hover::before 
{ width: 70%; }`

Thank you!